# continuous rational value function in R

Tags: real-analysis

Can there be a continuous non-constant function with only rational values defined on an interval in R?
          Or is the whole property meaningless?

Comment: Any continuous image of a connected space is connected, the only connected subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ are a point and intervals (possibly infinite).

Comment: Continuous functions on the reals have the intermediate value property; if they take on the values $a$ and $b$ then they take on every value between $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2):

No. Assume there was such an $\,f \,:\, [a,b] \to \mathbb{Q}$. If its' non-constant there are $x,y \in [a,b]$ with $f(x) \neq f(y)$. You can then pick $c$ from $[f(x),f(y)] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, since that set is non-empty. Now, can you show that there's an $z$ between $x$ and $y$ for which $f(z)=c$?. If so, you have a contradiction, since $f(z) = c \notin \mathbb{Q}$ per the choice of $c$.

**Hint**: Use that $f$ is continous for the missing part.